# Javascript: Sound on mouseover

Tags: javascript

I am designing a page, how would I trigger a ***sound- (audio file)*** on *mouseover* event on all the anchor tags contained within the page. I have this code so far how do I bind it to all `a` tags not just one. Any help appreciated.

```
function playclip(){ 
    'use strict';
    var audio = document.getElementById("hover-audio");  
    audio.play();
    audio.volume = 0.2;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this getElementsByTagName("a")

Comment: Oh god why would you do this...?

Comment: Where would I add that in - sorry quite new to JS, I just need all the tags to click on hover it seem pointless doing several different ones if a universal approach would work.

Comment: @Niet To learn that it is the absolute worst thing you could ever want to do in the history of web-pages? Why else?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback what are the alternative approaches. Appreciate any recommendations to help understand and improve...

Comment: What exactly isn't working now?

Comment: @Darren As a learning exercise, go for it. As a deliverable: think about it. Just say you have five anchor tags on a page (and that's small!) Each anchor tag is a ~1k image. But each tag gets a ~20k sound file attached to it - and that file sits on the server. The user loads the webpage, then moves the mouse around, moving over the anchor tags. The browser needs to download the file, but by the time it got it the mouse has moved on - perhaps on to another anchor tag, which is busily trying to download _its_ file. The wrong files get played for each tags. As sample/beatbox/stutter, it's great!

Comment: The functionality is weird, dangerous and wrong, but he is asking for a specific problem, and we don't are who can judge him.

Comment: Thank you, John that's really helpful and makes a lot of sense very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just JavaScript:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// Add onmouseover event for all a tags
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
   anchors[i].onmouseover = playclip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`audio` is an HTML tag in which you can put a `source` tag that points to a sound file, just like an image.

To play the sound you can call upon the element with the `.play()` function in JavaScript.

```
<audio id="my-sound">
    <source src="sound/asdf.mp3"/>
</audio>
```

```
$("a").mouseenter(functon(){
  $("#my-sound").play();
});
```